# How to does the token prevent csrf attack?

Tags: javascript, security, csrf, csrf-protection

I have read about CSRF and how the Unpredictable Synchronizer Token Pattern is used to prevent it. I didn't quite understand how it works.

Let's take this scenario :

A user is logged into a site with this form:

```
<form action="changePassword" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="password"><br>
   <input type="hidden" name="token" value='asdjkldssdk22332nkadjf' >
</form>
```

The server also stores the token in the session. When the request is sent it compares the token in the form data to the token in the session.

How does that prevent CSRF when the hacker can write JavaScript code that will:

1. Send a GET request to the site
2. Receive html text containing the request form.
3. Search the html text for the CSRF token.
4. Make the malicious request using that token.

Am missing something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The attacker can't use JavaScript to read the token from the site, because it would be a cross-origin request and access to the data from it is blocked (by default) by the Same Origin Policy ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)).

Take this for example:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://google.com");
xhr.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
    console.log(this.responseText);  
});
xhr.send();
```

The JS console reports:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://google.com/`. No '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: It's worth noting, that you can issue a successful GET reqauest also by iframe, script or object tag, but browser won't allow you do get loaded document content from JavaScript (Protocols, domains, and ports must match),

Comment: In case anyone was wondering why the attacker cannot just get any old token from the site, and use that in their request, it is because the token is also stored as a cookie in the browser which the attacker has no knowledge of, so when he sends the request with a new token he has just gotten from the site it does not match the one on the user's cookie and the request is dropped.

Comment: If I were to send a request using command line (for example CURL request), would that bypass Same Origin Policy?

Answer (score -2):

It's important to realize that CSRF attacks only happen in the browser. The user's session with the target server is used by the malicious server to forge requests. So how does #1 happen? Two options: you could make the #1 request from the malicious server, but that would simply return a CSRF token for the *server's* session, or you could make the #1 request using AJAX which, as you correctly identified, would return the CSRF token of the victim user.

Browsers have implemented HTTP access control for this very reason. You must use the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to restrict which domains may make AJAX requests to your server. In other words your server will ensure the browser doesn't let the malicious site do #1. Unfortunately the documents I've read on the matter aren't very clear about it, but I think that's because servers by default do not send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header unless configured to do so. If you do need to allow AJAX requests, you must either trust any origins in the header not to perform a CSRF attack, you can selectively lock down sensitive portions of your application to not allow AJAX requests, or use the other `Access-Control-*` headers to protect yourself.

> Using a Synchronizer Token is one way that an application can rely
>   upon the Same-Origin Policy to prevent CSRF by maintaining a secret
>   token to authenticate requests

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

You should read up on [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (CORS).

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` does not prevent CSRF, all it does is open up the restrictions imposed by the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). The Same Origin Policy does not prevent requests being made to your domain, it just stops the response from being read. The SOP can prevent the synchronizer token from being read though, but it is useless on its own for preventing CSRF.

Comment: "You must use the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header" — No. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` **relaxes** the security. It is secure by default.  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is used if you *want* third party sites to be able to read your data.